# How can i use table.insert without it inserting the index?

Tags: lua

```lua
local t={}
for i,v in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
  if v~=game.Players.LocalPlayer then
   table.insert(t,v.Name)
  end
end
```

if i do table.foreach(t,print) it also shows the index and it causes problems when i want to select a random player. The error usually tends to be something like "1 is not a valid member of workspace"

Comment: try `t[#t+1] = v.Name` instead `table.insert`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not that table.insert adds an index, but that you use it instead of the value you want do use.

`table.insert` inserts an element to a list. If no index is given the value is added to the end of the list.

So there is no way to use `table.insert` without "inserting the index". Actually there is no way at all to add an element to a Lua table without providing a key. A Lua table is nothing but a set of key value pairs.

`table.foreach` calls a function for each key value pair.
You should rather use `table.foreachi` btw.

So `table.foreachi(t, print)` is equivalent to

```
print(1, t[1])
print(2, t[2])
...
```

If you just want to print the values:

```
for i,v in ipairs(t) do print(v) end
```

or for older Lua versions

```
table.foreachi(t, function(i,v) print(v) end)
```

Alternatively you run a numeric for loop:

```
for i = 1, t.n do print(t[i]) end
```

or

```
for i = 1, #t do print(t[i]) end
```

Answer (score 0):

`table.foreach(t,f)` applies the function `f` to each *key-value* pair of `t` as [is written](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableLibraryTutorial). Also, since Lua 5.1 the function is deprecated.

If you want simply to print all values, do

```lua
for _, name in ipairs (t) do
    print (name)
end
```

or

```lua
print (table.concat (t, ', '))
```

If you want a random name from `t`:

```lua
local random_name = t [math.random (#t)]
```